# Postinstall not getting NODE_ENV

Tags: heroku, heroku-nodejs

When I deploy my node app to the Heroku, after it's done installing its dependancies, it does an "`npm run postinstall`" as per the docs, however the `NODE_ENV` variable isn't set, so my app is being build in development mode.

Simple solution would be to add `NODE_ENV=production` to the front, but this would cause issues when deploying to staging. Their documentation says that the variable should be set, but it's not. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply go to heroku and set the NOD_ENV variable by doing the following in your terminal:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Or you can simply go to heroku settings and set the config vars.